# Send email after node save based on a checkbox in a vocabulary

Tags: 7, rules

I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

I have a content type called "News", this content type has three fields (Title, Date, Body)

I have vocabulary called "Contacts", this vocabulary has multiple fields including a "Receive all notifications" field and an "Email" field.

My scenario is when a "News" item is saved, I want an email to be sent to each contact term from the "Contacts" vocabulary that has the "Receive all notifications" field checked. The email address pulls from the "Email" field.

Is this possible using rules? I'm having a difficult time trying to get fields to show for the vocabulary when it's not related to the news node that is being saved.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: yes, is possible but node and vocabulary must be entity reference related

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using? 7 or 8? There are several ways you could archive this 1) Create custom rule action 2) Write a hook on node_intert or 3) Write a service.